# which js function is loading when opening a form in odoo 14

Tags: javascript, odoo, odoo-14

I have tried the following code.It is working fine.But it is loading only onetime.when we enter to another form itis not working.

so i want to know the js function which call on loading a form in odoo 14

```
    var FormView = require('web.FormView');
    FormView.include({
     init: function() {
      this._super.apply(this, arguments);
      if (this.controllerParams.modelName === 'fee.payment') {
        console.log('dddddddd')
        console.log('fgfg',this)
        if (this.model){
        if(this.model.localData.fee.payment_1.data.state=="payed"){
                this.rendererParams.activeActions.edit = false;
                }
       }
       }
    }
});
});
```

Answer (score 1):

The JS views in Odoo 14.0 has a View, Renderer, Model and Controller. The View is only loaded once and has the job to load the XML. I think you can rather override the functions inside the Controller.

```
var web_client = require('web.web_client');
var FormController = require('web.FormController');

FormController.include({

    updateButtons: function () {
        var sup = this._super();
        var currentState = web_client._current_state;
        if (currentState) {
            var resModel = currentState.model;
            var resId = currentState.id;
            console.log("updateButtons");
            console.log(resModel);
            console.log(resId);
            console.log(this.mode);
        }
        return sup;
    },

    _setMode: function (mode, recordID) {
        var sup = this._super.apply(this, arguments);
        var currentState = web_client._current_state;
        var resModel = currentState.model;
        var resId = currentState.id;
        console.log("_setMode");
        console.log(resModel);
        console.log(resId);
        return sup;
    },

    _onCreate: function () {
        var sup = this._super();
        console.log("_onCreate");
        return sup;
    },

    _onDeleteRecord: function () {
        var sup = this._super();
        console.log("_onDeleteRecord");
        return sup;
    },

    _onDiscard: function () {
        var sup = this._super();
        console.log("_onDiscard");
        return sup;
    },

    _onDuplicateRecord: async function () {
        var sup = this._super();
        console.log("_onDuplicateRecord");
        return sup;
    },

    _onEdit: function () {
        var sup = this._super();
        console.log("_onEdit");
        return sup;
    },

    _onSave: function (ev) {
        var sup = this._super(ev);
        console.log("_onSave");
        return sup;
    },

});
```

Comment: no function is loading on entering xml

Comment: Are you sure that your JS file is loading?

Comment: yes,the xml file is loading

Comment: Sorry, then I don't know what the problem is